# using require in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use the uaparser.php library to detect the operating system, but when I use the following it just loads the github page for the library. This is the github page https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/php

```
 <?php

  require('uaparser.php');
  ?>
```

I've placed the file in my includes folder which resides in the Views directory. Perhaps, that is the source of the problem? Where would be an appropriate place to put this file?

Comment: Are you including the file from a view or a controller method? Also, are you sure that the content of the file is correct? You said it loads the GitHub page for the library. That makes me wonder what's actually inside the file.

Comment: **but when I use the following it just loads the github page for the library.** unexpected and unclear... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you downloaded uaparser.php you clicked File->Save Page As... (or something simular). That is why the page loads when you require/include it.

Open up the local file uaparser.php and confirm that it is actually the php code and not the html of the page.

Doing this is fine anywhere you need it.
You can place this anywhere, but for codeigniter it should be in the 3rd party folder, but it doesn't matter.